# C# Splitting another string

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am wanting to split the next string which is "L" but it is not working for some reason. I have managed to make this work for my first substring and it seems to be working but this is not working for my second substring which should return "L" within the console in a new line or the 20th character. Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace employeefinal
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            employee i = new employee();
            Console.WriteLine(i.getName());
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(i.getCity());
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
        public class employee
        {
            string employeename = "Name:John How Smith L, U, 012, 2, 7, 2, 4";


            public employee()
            {

            }

            public string getName()
            {
                return employeename.Substring(0, 19).Trim();
            }

            public string getCity()
            {
                return employeename.Substring(19, 20).Trim();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is getting returned?

Comment: @Steve as you can see within my main I am returning my getName which gets the substring 0 to 19th character of string. I am now trying to return my getCity which should return 19 t0 20th character but this is not appearing within the console even though I have called it within my main.

Comment: Is anything appearing in the console?

Comment: The second parameter for `Substring` is the length, not the ending index.  You want `Substring(19, 1)`.

Comment: @Steve essentially I want to return L which stands for London but this is not appearing within my console. The method for this is getCity

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, I'm asking what is actually happening. Is anything getting returned from your second substring?

Comment: @Steve nope it is not returning anything except the full string in the console.

Comment: @PaulAbbott thanks this seems to be working :)

Comment: Learn to use [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx) - it covers things like this quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

With [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) the second parameter is the length of the substring. If you just want getCity to return 'L' you could change it to:

```
    return employeename.Substring(20,1).Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Substring() method accepts two things one is character position and length from that position. In your code GetName() returns starting from zero position to 19th position and in 2nd method ie GetCity() returns from 19th position to rest of character in that string. So substring(19,2) will work I guess.